# How to use LD_PRELOAD in container runc

Tags: linux, docker, containers, ld-preload, runc

I followed this [link](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc#using-runc) and tried to use `runc` to launch a busybox container. I wanted to load a shared library into the container process with the `LD_PRELOAD` trick. I modified the `args` in `config.json`

```
        "args": [
                "sh"
        ],
```

to

```
        "args": [
                "LD_PRELOAD=preload.so sh"
        ],
```

It does not work as I expected. Is there a way to load a shared library with runc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to preload a shared library with `runc`:

```
        "args": [                                                       
                "sh"                                                  
        ],                                                              
        "env": [                                                        
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "TERM=xterm",                                           
                "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/init.so"    
        ],
```